# Update junction table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here is my tables

```
Proposal
--------------
Id | ProposalNo

SalesCall
---------------
Id

SalesCallReference (Junction Table)
---------------
Id | ProposalID | SalesCallID
```

A sales call can be related to many proposals

So in my form for sales calls, I got a continuous subform with a list of `proposalNo`. There's a combobox to display and select a proposalNo to link.

but when I choose a new proposal, MS-Access makes a new id for the proposal instead of `salesCallReference.id`

So it creates new empty proposals.

**How to update only the junction table `SalesCallReference` and why MS ACCESS creates a new ID for the proposal when I add a proposal?**

the combobox in the subform has 2 columns, the `proposalNo` and the `ProposalId`. I tried to update the hidden `proposalId` textbox on the click event of the combobox but no luck.

if it helps, here's my query to load the subform

```
SELECT Proposals.ProposalID, Proposals.ProposalNo, SalesCallReference.ProposalID, SalesCallReference.ID, SalesCallReference.SalesCallID AS ReferenceSalesID
FROM Proposals 
   INNER JOIN SalesCallReference ON Proposals.ProposalID = SalesCallReference.ProposalID;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the main form uses `SalesCall` (or a query based on `SalesCall`) as its record source.  In that case, use `SalesCallReference` as the subform record source and set link master field to `SalesCall.Id` and link child field to `SalesCallReference.SalesCallID`.  That way new subform rows will "inherit" their `SalesCallID` values from the parent form.

Use a combo or list box for `ProposalID` in the subform.

Comment: Sorry I submitted that before I saw the update to your question.  I may be off the mark, but I suspect the link master/child properties on the subform control are implicated here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the master/child links but it's done like this already. I will remove all the controls beside the combo box and try your answer. I thought I needed to make a control for each item in the table. Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you use just the `SalesCallReference` table as the subform record source?

Comment: Great, it works. The problem was the record source. I changed it to salescallReference like you said instead of my query and I get the proposalno for the combobox with a query instead. Thank you!